# Unable to call methods or access methods outside of onHandleIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So this is has me stumped
I'm simply trying to start my service when Google's API Activity Recognition detects certain parameters.
So I have extended `IntentService` and implemented `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

Logcat confirms the service works (with surprisingly accurate predictions) 
If anyone is interested this is how I activate the service:

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)){
        ActivityRecognitionResult recognitionResult = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        parseResults(recognitionResult.getProbableActivities());
        //My method to read the results from the list, logcat confirms it is working correctly

}

    @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    useActivityUpdates = true;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CA.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(googleApiClient, 100, pendingIntent);
    Log.i("CA", "Connected");
}
```

So as you can see in the `onHandleIntent` I am calling a parseResults function.

```
    public long elapsedTimeGoogleAPI;
private void parseResults( List<DetectedActivity> detectedActivities){
    PredictedActivity newActivity = new PredictedActivity();
    newActivity.bicycle = 0;
    newActivity.onFoot = 0;
    newActivity.unknown = 0;
    newActivity.vehicle = 0;
    newActivity.walking = 0;
    newActivity.running = 0;
    newActivity.still = 0;
    Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "NewActivity");

    newActivity.elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTimeGoogleAPI;
    for (DetectedActivity dt : detectedActivities){
        switch (dt.getType()){
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                newActivity.vehicle = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "v: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                newActivity.bicycle = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "b: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
            case DetectedActivity.WALKING:
                newActivity.walking = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "w: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                newActivity.onFoot = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "of: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
            case DetectedActivity.RUNNING:
                newActivity.running = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "r: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
                newActivity.unknown = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "u: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                newActivity.still = dt.getConfidence();
                Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "s: " + dt.getConfidence());

                break;
        }
    }
    if (predictedActivities == null){
        predictedActivities = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.i("CAActivityDetect", "predictedActivities == null New ArrayList");

    }
    predictedActivities.add(newActivity);
}
```

So in another method in the class where the API is constructed and activated, I initialize my `PredictedActivity` list and I put a log there for reference...
I also have another Runnable loop reading the most recent item from this list.

These are the logcat results:

```
130|shell@tilapia:/ $ logcat | grep "CAActivityDetect"
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): New ArrayList
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): Attempt connect
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): Connected
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): NewActivity
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): s: 100
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): predictedActivities == null New ArrayList
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): NewActivity
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): s: 100
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): predictedActivities == null New ArrayList
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): NewActivity
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): s: 100
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): predictedActivities == null New ArrayList
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): NewActivity
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): s: 100
I/CAActivityDetect(19902): predictedActivities == null New ArrayList
```

So this leaves me to believe that somehow, despite all of this code living in the same instance of a class, that somehow IntentService is not able to edit information used by the class somehow... `parseResults` is used exclusively by the IntentService methods and works fine, but when I try to add to a list used by the main program every time it creates a new ArrayList as if it can't access the same variable it used the last time or that the rest of the class uses. 
I feel like I'm going insane haha!

Comment: I can't see anything that would suggest `predictedActivities` shouldn't be `null`.

Comment: I have a log.i every time anything is done to this var, line 2 of the logcat output is when the arraylist in question gets assigned to a new ArrayList<>()

Comment: And even that how do you explain the fact that the if statement in onhandleintent keeps detecting null